# Create custom column in post table in wordpress

Tags: plugins, database, table

I want to add two custom field to table wp_posts, and that I need for my plugin. now to enable these fields I have changed core file of wordpress

```
wordpress/wp-admin/post.php
$data = compact( array( 'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_date_gmt', 'post_content', 'post_content_filtered', 'post_title', 'post_excerpt', 'post_status', 'post_type', 'comment_status', 'ping_status', 'post_password', 'post_name', 'to_ping', 'pinged', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'post_parent', 'menu_order', 'post_mime_type', 'guid' ) );
```

here I have added two fields which I want.

Now I want these things as installable( I have manually added two fields here).

So how to do that within plugin.

I have read one post http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/add-a-custom-column-in-posts-and-custom-post-types-admin-screen/ here hooks are used in theme function.php,but i want to do in plugin itself.

I am using wordpress 3.6.

still any confusion please comment I will update.

Comment: put the code in a plugin. a hook is a hook, doesn't matter if it's in a theme or a plugin. I should point out here that modifying a core file should never be done, as well as modifying a core table. use post meta if you need to store additional data for a post.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be editing core files, it makes it very difficult to upgrade.

Use the [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function and put it in a plugin file.

See example below, this plugin will add a meta box to all pages in your wordpress installation. Just edit it for your own means...

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: META Data Plugin
Plugin URI: http://eddsmith.me
Description: Adds a META description box to all pages.
Version: 1.0
Author: Edd Smith
Author URI: http://eddsmith.me
*/
?>
<?php

add_action('admin_init','metadescription_meta_box_init');

function metadescription_meta_box_init() {

    // The Function that creates the meta box
    add_meta_box('metadescription-meta',__('META description','metadescription-plugin'), 'metadescription_meta_box', 'page','advanced','default'); 

    // hook to save our meta box data when the page is saved
    add_action('save_post','metadescription_save_meta_box');  

}


function metadescription_meta_box($post,$box) {

    // retrieve our custom meta box values
    $metadescription = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_metadescription',true);

    // custom meta box form elements
    echo '<p>' .__('Enter META description below. Remember... <br/>#1 -Search engines truncate the description at 160 characters<br/>#2 - Leave blank and search engines will choose text for you<br/>#3 - Since 2009 META descriptions do not influence Googles ranking algorithms. ','metadescription-plugin'). ': <input type="text" name="metadescription" value="'.esc_attr($metadescription).'" style="width:100%;"></p>';    

}


function metadescription_save_meta_box($post_id,$post) {
    // if post is a revision skip saving our meta box data
    if($post->post_type == 'revision') { return; }


    // process form data if $_POST is set
    if(isset($_POST['metadescription'])) {

    // save the meta box data as post meta using the post ID as a unique prefix
    update_post_meta($post_id,'_metadescription', esc_attr($_POST['metadescription']));
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: An example would be great with a short explanation. Link only answers are useless, specially if that links gets removed in future (we have no control over links outside WPSE). Please [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/145595/edit) your answer and add relevant info. Just one more thing, the filename is functions.php, not function.php. I have already corrected that

Answer (score 0):

In this code I am changing the columns of my edit.php page, I am basically keeping only the checkbox, author and date I am adding acf fields from the posts to the edit.php page but you can add other meta there.

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Custom Columns
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function my_posts_columns($columns) {
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'thumbnail' => 'Снимка',
        'title' => 'Заглавие на обявата',
        'category' => 'Категория',
        'sub-cat' => 'Под-категория',
        'author' => 'Автор',
        'date' => 'Дата',
    );
    return $columns;
}

function my_custom_columns($column) {
    global $post;
    if ($column == 'thumbnail') {
        if (get_field('photos')) {
            $images = get_field('photos');
            $image_1 = $images[0];
            echo '<img src="' . $image_1['url'] . '" style="max-width:150px;" alt="' . $images['alt'] . '" />';
        } else {
            echo 'Няма изображение..';
        }
    }

    if ($column == 'category') {
        if (get_field('select-category')) {
            echo the_field('select-category');
        } else {
            echo 'Unknown';
        }
    }
    if ($column == 'sub-cat') {
        if (get_field('sub-cat-auto')) {
            echo the_field('sub-cat-auto');
        }
    }
}

add_action("manage_posts_custom_column", "my_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_posts_columns", "my_posts_columns");
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Sortable Columns
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function cat_column_register_sortable($columns) {
    $columns ['category'] = 'category';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter("manage_edit-post_sortable_columns", "cat_column_register_sortable");

function subcat_column_register_sortable($columns) {
    $columns ['sub-cat'] = 'sub-cat';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter("manage_edit-post_sortable_columns", "subcat_column_register_sortable");
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Custom Columns END
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```